# How to prevent anonymous access to _layout pages

Tags: feature-activation, anonymous-authentication

I am JR.System Admin in Sharepoint and I am trying to prevent anonymous users to `access _layouts` pages. I used this shell command with this instructions:

- `get-spfeature -site http:// maximum.dmzisbank`
- `disable-spfeature viewformpageslockdown -url http:// maximum.dmzisbank`
- On Extend Site  ( from page to the internet -  _layouts/user.aspx  ) disable anonymous accessing.
- web application -> authentication providers -> from internet -> Enable Anonymous Authentication -> Uncheck
- Execute Find-BrokenInheritance.ps1 -url http:// maximum.dmzisbank . (Remove the broken inheritances with this step)
- `enable-spfeature viewformpageslockdown -url http:// maximum.dmzisbank`
- web application -> authentication providers -> on internet -> Enable Anonymous Authentication -> check
- from site of Extend  ( from page to internet -  _layouts/user.aspx  ) enable anonymous accessing.
- web application -> authentication providers -> on internet -> IIS Authentication Settings -> Integrated Windows authentication -> Uncheck

It does not work as I wanted and I have taken 401 Error​ after using this. So Does anybody know anything how can I solve this situation ?